# JQuery Variable.parent().addclass attempts not working

Tags: jquery

```
if (lastclicked == 'undefined'){
    $('#Info-Side-Tabs a:#Main').parent().addClass('active');
} else {
    $('#Info-Side-Tabs a:lastclicked').parent().addClass('active');
}
```

lastclicked can tell you the last link you clicked on my side tab switcher. It will not change upon clicking on the show/hide and. What I am trying to do is, when you have not clicked on any tabs and hide the tabs, the active class will switch to the close/open tab but the content will not change. So if lastclicked is undefined, of which it will be as you've not cliked on anything else, when you reopen, the active tab will switch back to the default. If it is not undefined, the same situation but there is a current possibility of two tabs for the active class to go back to.

My full JQuery Code:

```
$('#Info-Side-Tabs a').click(function() {
    var clicked = $(this).attr('href');
    if (clicked == "#Map-Selection-Info-Close") {
        $('#Info-Side-Tabs li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        $(this).attr("href","#Map-Selection-Info-Open");
        $(this).text('Open Me');
        $('#Map-Selection-Info').animate({marginLeft: '978px'}, 1000);
        $('#ATWI80C-Map').animate({width: '900px' }, 1000);
    } else if (clicked == "#Map-Selection-Info-Open") {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
        $(this).attr("href","#Map-Selection-Info-Close");
        $(this).text('Close Me');
        $('#Map-Selection-Info').animate({marginLeft: '670px'}, 1000);
        $('#ATWI80C-Map').animate({width: '600px' }, 1000);
        if (lastclicked == 'undefined'){
            $('#Info-Side-Tabs a:#Main').parent().addClass('active');
        } else {
            $('#Info-Side-Tabs a:lastclicked').parent().addClass('active');
        }
    } else {
        lastclicked = clicked;
        switchback = $('clicked');
        $('#Info-Side-Tabs li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        var activeTab = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#tab-content > div:visible').hide();
        $(activeTab).show();
    }
    //alert(lastclicked);
});
```

I have tried all sorts, this is just the current attempt.

Live View: https://tornhq.com/WorkingOn/InteractiveMap/implementing.html#Map-Selection-Info-Close

Comment: @Jean Hules I do not understand how to use what you have suggested. This is actually my first big thing i8n JQuery I have done, I don't understand how what you have suggested will call the last clicked or is this a function to replace the 'if' statement inside of the 'else if' statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
if (lastclicked == 'undefined'){
```

To this:

```
if (typeof lastclicked === "undefined"){
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UhDKq/1/

To test it in the fiddle, change the line

```
var lastclicked;
```

to

```
var lastclicked = "#Anything";
```

Then switch it back again.

Not that `lastclick` is not set until it falls all the way through the `if` which it won't do if "Close Me" or "Open Me" is clicked.

```
if (clicked == "#Map-Selection-Info-Close") {  // Close Me
    //code
} else if (clicked == "#Map-Selection-Info-Open") { // Open Me
    //code
    if (typeof lastclicked === "undefined") {
            alert("undefined");
            //$('#Info-Side-Tabs a:#Main').parent().addClass('active');
            $('#Info-Side-Tabs li#Main a').addClass('active'); 
        } else {
            alert("defined");
            //$('#Info-Side-Tabs a:lastclicked').parent().addClass('active');
            $('#Info-Side-Tabs a[href="' + lastclicked + '"').parent().addClass('active');
        }
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, however it has no effect. Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: I have updated my live version with your implementation so you can have a look.

Comment: @TimMarshall Works as you coded it. You are not setting 'lastclicked` until it falls through your `if` statement. So, if you click on "Close Me," `lastclick` isn't set and then if you click on "Open Me," `lastclick` isn't set.

Comment: Hence why I am doing 'if (lastclicked == 'undefined'){' to check if anything has been clicked or not, if any other tab has already been clicked it will not be set, but please bare with me for 5 mins, I am attempting a theory I have for it.

Comment: @TimMarshall `lastclick` is set when you click a tab other than "Close" or "Open". Just uncomment the `alert(lastclicked);` under the `if` statement to see.

Comment: Yes, I understand that part, that comment you talk of is for testing. I have updated the live view, I am stuck with no idea on what to do. I do  not know how to set the variable to #Main to start with, when I do it says that it is an error. If I can set the variable, the 'if, else' statement can be removed.

Comment: Okay, I didn't notice only one equal sign, of which I have edited and updated, I have tried both my original way and your way, however I still cannot get any change back to work.

Comment: @TimMarshall I changed my answer to add your `active` classes. You might want to consider cleaning up the DOM. You are using multiple `id`'s with the same name (`id="Main"` is repeated). This is going to make it harder for you to code the jquery. Also, it appears that you are attempting to target DOM elements by their `href` attribute and, while not impossible, it makes for harder to maintain and understand code.

Comment: Okay, so now the alert is working but '$('#Info-Side-Tabs  a#Main a').parent().addClass('active');' and '$('#Info-Side-Tabs a[href="' + lastclicked + '"').parent().addClass('active');' I now need to work out as it is not the a href which has the active class, it is their parent where the active class should be.

Comment: Sorry about my edited quote of you, the first one is meant to say '$('#Info-Side-Tabs li#Main a').addClass('active');'

Comment: Got it working!!! 'var lastclicked = "#Main";' so one is set by default and simply, with no 'If, else' statement; $('a[href=' + lastclicked + ']').parent().addClass('active');